# Inner product properties

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

how prove the properties of inner produtcs on the formula

$$
\left( \sum_{j} a_{j}x^{j}, \sum_{i} b_{i}x^{i} \right) 
= \sum_{i,j} \frac{a_{j}b_{i}}{i+j+1}
$$

to show that $(,)$ is a inner product on $R[x]$?

the properties are

$(x,y+z) = (x,y) + (x,z)$

$(x,y) = \overline{(y,x)}$

$(x,x) > 0$ if and only if $x \neq 0$

Comment: I assume you might have tried and got stuck some where... tell us what you have tried

Comment: yeah, for the first i try $
\left( \sum_{j} a_{j}x^{j}, \sum_{i} a_{i}x^{i} + \sum_{k}a_{k}x^{k} \right) 
$ then i try show that $
 \sum_{i,j,k} \frac{a_{j}a_{i}a_{k}}{i+j+k+1} =  \sum_{j,i} \frac{a_{j}a_{i}}{i+j+1} + \sum_{j,k} \frac{a_{j}a_{k}}{i+k+1} $ but i have no idea to how "broke" the $\sum_{i,j,k}$ in two sum`s

Comment: once you showed it is bilinear and symmetric, you have to prove it is definite positve : $(P(x),P(x)) \ge 0$ and $(P(x),P(x)) = 0 \implies P(x) = 0$

Comment: @EduardoSilva: Why are you using the letter $a to denote the coefficients of all three series? It will just confuse you.

Comment: sorry, i will correct this and use $b_i$ and $c_k$ instead

Comment: sorry, i will correct this and use $b_i$ and $c_k$ instead

Comment: an hint for $(x,x) > 0$ : if a matrix $A$ is positive definite, what can you say of the matrix $M_{ij} = A_{ij} - A_{ij} B_{ij}$ where $|B_{ij}| < 1$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: note that
$$
(p(x),q(x))=\int_0^1 p(x)q(x)\,dx
$$

Comment: its become trivial isn't? now i just have to use the integral properties

Comment: @EduardoSilva Yes, that's the idea! See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix